# Ansible conditional template variable substitution

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to create configuration files from a template with include variables based on the fourth character of `{{ ansible_hostname }}`.

What works:

**playbook:**

```
---
- hosts: spock
  roles:
   - templaterole
```

**role:**

```
---
- name: testing autofs template on spock
  template:
    src=autofs
    dest=/tmp/autofs
  with_items: 
     - "{{ var_a }}"
  when: ('{{ ansible_hostname }}' == "spock")
```

**vars/main.yml:**

```
var_a:
  -
     var_1: 'this is var_a1'
     var_2: 'this is var_a2'
var_b:
  -
     var_1: 'this is var_b1'
     var_2: 'this is var_b2'
```

**template:**

```
{{ item.var_1 }}
#
{{ item.var_2 }}
#
```

This works as expected and the output produces a /tmp/autofs file on the spock host that looks like:

```
this is var_a1
#
this is var_a2
#
```

Now, if I try to write the file based on trying to pull out the 4th character of the `{{ ansible_hostname }}`, the play does not get a match on the conditional and does not write the file.  I'm trying this conditional in my role:

```
---
- name: testing autofs template on spock
  template:
    src=autofs
    dest=/tmp/autofs
  with_items: 
     - "{{ var_a }}"
  when: ('{{ ansible_hostname }} | cut -c4' == "c") or
        ('{{ ansible_hostname }} | cut -c4' == "k")
```

the play skips this task due to not matching on the conditional.  Ultimately i want to be able to pull any 4th character of our hostnames as this will always be predictable (can only be one of 4 known characters which defines my environment and lets me define the correct template variables based on these diff production environments.)

Can anyone help me to redefine my when statement such that i can do or conditionals and pull characters out of defined ansible variables like ansible_hostname?

Comment: When you use the pipe it sends the result of the first command....but that is a variable not the name of a command. So most likely it is using a command not found. Maybe if you just got the char at 4th pos with `{{ ansible_hostname[3] }} == "c"` it would work

Comment: I don't believe you that the first conditional works correctly. It will always evaluate to false. Please read the docs on `when` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use curly brackets inside `when` statement, it's already a Jinja2 statement.
And in Jinja2 statements you use `|` to apply filter, but there is no `cut` filter available.

Your statement should be as simple as:

```
when: ansible_hostname[3] in 'ck'
```